# convert Matrix of type CV_32FC1 to CV_64FC1

Tags: opencv, matrix, double

How do I convert a cv::Mat of type CV_32FC1 to the type CV_64FC1 (equivalent to a change from float to double)?

I am opening a Matrix that was saved as XML (`cvSave`) but as a float. This means that the field `<dt>` has the value `f` in the file. I need to change it to `d` to open it. But I'd rather not do this, instead I'd like to open it directly as a Matrix with elements of type double, or convert it later from float to double.

Below is my code for opening the file.

```
/** Load cv::Mat from XML file. 
 */
cv::Mat loadMat(const std::string filename)
{
    cv::Mat result;
    cv::FileStorage fs(filename, cv::FileStorage::READ);
    fs.getFirstTopLevelNode() >> result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Okay, I'm a dimwit. Here is how it goes:

There is the function convertTo that does exactly what I want.

Thanks for [matrix type conversion in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489492/matrix-type-conversion-in-opencv) for pointing this out.

Here is how I do it:

```
cv::Mat A = loadMat("mymat.xml"); // See function loadMat in the question!
A.convertTo(A, CV_64F);
```

Comment: Also, if you're converting from something like 16U to 8U, you need to add a scaling factor as a third parameter. `A.convertTo(A, CV_8UC1, 255.0/65536.0);`

Comment: (Dimwitticism or not, your question-and-answer allowed me to find the keyword [convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b). It's hard to look something up in the doc without knowing its name!)

Note that this example `A.convertTo(A, CV_64F)` is ambiguous about the direction of the conversion when it is not doing convertion in-place. It is, in fact, `source.convertTo(destination, new_type, ...)`. This is completely in keeping with OpenCV style, but I missed that, had it backwards, and spent a while trying to understand my mistake.