# How to convert Point2f[] to Point[] OpenCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

Other than creating a function that puts elements one by one, is there a method that converts Point2f[] to Point[] datatype?

Comment: your question should have shown some research effort https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Opencv convertTo method.

```
cv::Mat A = loadMat("mymat.xml"); // See function loadMat in the question!
A.convertTo(A, CV_64F);
```

Picked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910332/convert-matrix-of-type-cv-32fc1-to-cv-64fc1). Pick your appropriate data type.